# Trying to enable https on apache server in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: apache, https

I've got an installation of the apache2 package on Ubuntu 12.04, and I've installed the PHP mod so that I can run PHP scripts on my server. I'm now trying to set up the server for HTTPS. The application I'm working on needs to have https access enabled, but I've never had much experience with SSL, certs, or any of that security stuff (I'm trying to learn, however).

I've tried following tutorials online, but there always seems to be a failure with each tutorial. Here's my most recent attempt:

```
sudo make-ssl-cert generate-default-snakeoil --force-overwrite
sudo a2enmod ssl
sudo a2ensite default-ssl
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

This series of commands doesn't output any errors, but when I navigate to https://, it tells me the webpage is not available. Navigating to http:// works fine.

Am I missing something, or has this tutorial just led me astray? I'd really like to figure out how to enable Apache on Ubuntu 12.04 to handle https requests. :)

Comment: Take a look to http://www.linode.com/wiki/index.php/Apache2_SSL_in_Ubuntu

Comment: I did try that one as well, but one of the packages they reference (libapache-mod-ssl) doesn't exist in 12.04, only before 7.10. The rest of the tutorial commands seem to depend on having this package installed.

Comment: See http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=953607

Comment: I like this answer, it actually worked: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-ubuntu-14-04